# What's parked in Mil Moscow helicopter plant?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification, soviet-union

[This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/62590) has a photo of a [Mil Mi-26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-26) that I felt in love with, so I looked in Wikipedia and learned it's the largest production helicopter, second only to [Mil V-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_V-12) that flew as a prototype.

In turn, Wikipedia's V-12 article gave a link to the exact position where one of the two V-12 produced is placed, so I opened Google Maps and I had a satellite photo of the V-12!

So far so good, but when I zoomed out a little I saw many other helicopters parked around, all clearly helicopters except a cigar shaped beast, with winglets apparently too small for an airplane, in the upper right corner of the screen dump below, marked with an arrow... Remarkably I cannot see the shadows of the blades on the ground.

Could you please identify that object?

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Looks like a [**Mil Mi-6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-6) with the rotor removed (like the adjacent two to the right). Here is the [3-view drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mil_Mi-6_HOOK.png) overlaid:

[image]
(Google Earth @ 55°40'04.61" N  37°56'07.62" E)

The tail boom appears to be thicker than it is due to the angle, it'll make sense by taking the satellite's perspective. Note the fatter bottom:

[image]
Google Maps measurement; actual aircraft length is 33.18 m (108 ft 10 in).

Comment: Do I see a turbine engine under each wing. Could be a modern gyrocopter?

Comment: @Muze: What you're seeing are external fuel tanks. Visible if you check the Mi-6 link.