# Why not add more blades to a helicopter?

Tags: aircraft-design, helicopter

There's something that bothers me inherently, and just like the Hueys from Vietnam, 'only' having two blades.  Doesn't seem enough, I mean, if despite your best planning, engineering -- whatever -- you lose one, you're like a twisty brick plummeting to the ground; and on the way down, it won't be any value shouting "That shouldn't have happened!!"

OK, first up, I accept the higher centre of gravity thing, if I have 4 blades, f'instance, but that's an engineering problem that can be fixed, ie. that's no reason.

There must be some other reason I can't have -- if in fact I actually can't -- have 4 or 6 or... isn't there an Aerospatiale chopper with 9??

Please tell me what I don't understand....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! This is a good question...

Comment: Actually the most efficient would be to have a single blade. Multiple blades are always working in the wake of the leading blade.

Comment: See [Why don't helicopters prefer shorter rotors with more blades?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22399/14897) and [Why are three-bladed helicopters relatively rare?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32234/14897) Also, any rotor with one blade shot, would be extremely unstable and will also crash.

Comment: I should have said... I was actually thinking in the context of gyrocopters / gyroplanes.  

Yes, I  can see how a blade would be working in the wake of the one ahead of it, but I'm going to assume (obviously can be wrong) that a 4-bladed configuration is sufficiently separated for that not to be a limiting factor... for gyrocopters.

Comment: @ymb1 I would even call the second one a dupe. Peter's answer in particular covers most of what there is to solidity factor selection.

Comment: @SteveHlavenka Have a look at his answer: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/32252/23223 If that doesn't make it clear for you, could you explain what benefit do you expect to obtain by having more blades?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are three-bladed helicopters relatively rare?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32234/why-are-three-bladed-helicopters-relatively-rare)